Sobre formato global en Java
he leído varios post sobre el formato de números usando varias vías. Pero siempre son similares, establecer un formato determinado con las características deseadas y luego formatear el valor deseado usando el formato establecido. Mi pregunta es la siguiente: No existe una forma donde se pueda establecer el formato por defecto para la aplicación y a partir de allí todas las conversiones se realicen usando este formato y sin tener que pasar por parámetro el formato en cada llamada?
Saludos y gracias anticipadas.

Hola JavaPrinc, se me ocurre como primer aproximación, crear una clase envoltorio (por ejemplo JavaPrincTextField), que extienda a un JComponent y solo sobreescriba el método setText pasandole a super el texto formateado.

This question is similar to: Pregunta sobre variables static. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@RuslanLópez, maestro, parece que en un descuido, se le transpapelaron las páginas, este comentario no es para esta pregunta.

@MarcePuente el comentario es acertado, esa es al manera en que por ejemplo la clase Math pone a disposición de toda la JVM el valor de PI https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#PI, de la misma manera se pueden poner accesibles objetos como los formatters o incluso métodos. Solamente que sin código de ejemplo no me atrevería a darle una respuesta completa

@RuslanLópez, maestro, debe ser mi tontera natural, pero sigo sin entender que tienen que ver las variables estáticas...

@MarcePuente elabore su propia pregunta con su [mcve] y con gusto le explico, por cierto usted no es tonto, usted es muy valioso. Nunca se haga menos ni se de tan duro con sus propias palabras

@RuslanLópez, maestro, idolo, sus palabras (sobre todo porque usted es uno de los grandes!) me conmueven, no me engaño, se que me falta mucho para estar a su altura, pero que usted valore mi aporte... es la gloria, le debo muchos agradecimientos, de las respuestas que da a otros, me nutro, ahora uno más, GRACIAS!!
